# I want to add a new Classification to the Coverity webapp

Tags: coverity

Right now the Coverity web api has the following options for the "Classification" field for each finding:

Unclassified
Bug
Pending
False Positive
Intentional

I'd like to add "Bad Practice" to the list. Is this possible?

Comment: This has spawned a fair bit of internal discussion within the Coverity team. Would you be willing to expand on your use case to explain why you want to be able to classify defects as "Bad Practice" (as opposed to using Action/Severity)?

Comment: Well for instance, say I have an EXPLICIT_THIS_EXPECTED finding. It's not a bug. It compiles, it works, and there are no serious implications of doing it this way. To mark it as a bug or false positive is wrong. To mark it as intentional... well maybe it was intentional, but it's still not the right thing to mark it as. Bad Practice fits. The problem is a coverity report with hundreds of bugs is misleading, as those aren't actual bugs. They're something we'd like fixed if time allows. So many "bugs" in a report scares clients.

Comment: To that end, a "Fix recommended" instead of "Fix Required" would also be highly useful as a default option.

Comment: Another idea would be a "Outside of scope" entry for classifications. Often Coverity picks up issues in third-party tools which are outside of the scope of a code review. Right now we just set them to False Positive and Ignore, but it'd be nice if it was possible to make it clear the issues were not related to the codebase being reviewed.

Comment: This can be done with component maps - you are able to control what parts of the codebase are in each group, and whether you want to include those results or not.

Comment: The Component Map is nowhere to be seen, despite me being a Project Admin, @Caleb

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add element to the Classification list in Coverity.

You can add to the Action and Severity lists though.  So these might fill your need.

Comment: See doc/en/cov_platform_use_and_admin_guide.html#edit_attribute_value